# R: subsetting first 30 groups in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to find a way to subset the first 30 groups in my data frame (171 in total, of unequal length).
Here's a smaller dummy data frame I've been practicing with (in this case I only try to subsample the first 3 groups):

`groups=c(rep("A",times=5),rep("B",times=2), rep("C",times=3),rep("D",times=2), rep("E",times=8)) value=c(1,2,4,3,5,7,6,8,7,5,2,3,5,7,1,1,2,3,5,4) dummy<-data.frame(groups,value)`

So far, I've tried variations of:

`subset<-c("A","B","C") dummy2<-dummy[dummy$groups==subset,]`

but I get the following warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Would anyone know how to fix this or have other options?

Comment: You should get what you want if you replace `==` with `%in%` : `dummy2<-dummy[dummy$groups %in% subset,]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `filter` from `dplyr`.  Get the first 'n' `unique` elements of 'groups' with `head`, use `%in%` to return a logical vector in `filter` to subset the rows

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 4
dummy %>% 
     filter(groups %in% head(unique(groups), n))
```

or `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(dummy, groups %in% head(unique(groups), n))
```

---

`==` can be used either with equal length vectors (for elementwise comparison) or if `length` of the second vector is 1.  For multiple elements, use `%in%`